# R ggplot2 strange behaviour. It looks it's passing by reference

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to copy a ggplot object and then change some properties of the new copied object as, for instance, the colour line to red.

Assume this code:

```
df = data.frame(cbind(x=1:10, y=1:10))
a = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
b = a
```

Then, if I change the colour of line of variable `a`

```
a$layers[[1]]$geom_params$colour = "red"
```

it also changes the colour of `b`

```
> b$layers[[1]]$geom_params$colour 
[1] "red"    # why it is not "black"?
```

I wish I could have two different objects `a` and `b` with different characteristics. So, in order to do this in the correct way, I would need to call the plot again for `b` using `b = ggplot(df, aes(xy, y=z)) + geom_line()`. However, at this time in the algorithm, there is no way to know the plot command `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()`

Do you know what's wrong with this? Is ggplot objects treated in a different manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I agree that's a little spooky, but if you look at `str(a)` you'll notice that the layers are proto objects, so that most likely explains _why_ you're seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that `ggplot` uses the `proto` library to mimic OO-style objects. The `proto` library relies on environments to collect variables for objects. Environments are passed by reference which is why you are seeing the behavior you are (and also a reason no one would probably recommend changing the properties of a layer that way).

Anyway, adapting an example from the `proto` documentaiton, we can try to make a deep copy of the laters of the `ggplot` object. This should "disconnect" them. Here's such a helper function

```
duplicate.ggplot<-function(x) {
    require(proto)
    r<-x
    r$layers <- lapply(r$layers, function(x) {
        as.proto(as.list(x), parent=x)
    })
    r
}
```

so if we run

```
df = data.frame(cbind(x=1:10, y=1:10))
a = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
b = a
c = duplicate.ggplot(a)

a$layers[[1]]$geom_params$colour = "red"
```

then plot all three, we get

[image]

which shows we can change "c" independently from "a"

Comment: Nice. I was pondering whether there is a canonical way to do an assignment (at the R level, not at the C level) that guarantees a copy is made.

Comment: @joran I know of no way to force a deep copy of an environment in R code; but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist I guess.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. gives " Error in assign(s, x[[s]], envir = envir) : invalid 'envir' argument ". Any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the specifics of ggplot, there's a simple trick to make a deep copy of (almost) any object in R:

```
obj_copy <- unserialize(serialize(obj, NULL))
```

This serializes the object to a binary representation suitable for writing to disk and then reconstructs the object from that representation. It's equivalent to saving the object to a file and then loading it again (i.e. `saveRDS` followed by `readRDS`), only it never actually saves to a file. It's probably not the most efficient solution, but it should work for just about any object that can be saved to a file.

You can define a `deepcopy` function using this trick:

```
deepcopy <- function(p) {
    unserialize(serialize(p, NULL))
}
```

This seems to successfully break the links between related ggplots.

Obviously, this will not work for objects that cannot be serialized, such as big matrices from the bigmemory package.