# Assigned variable is changing when object is modified - ggplot

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2

I am running into an issue with ggplot.

I have a ggplot object `x1` that I assign to variable `y1`

I then modify `x1`, and assign it to `y2`.

As a result of my change to `x1`, `y1` is also changed. This is throwing me off a bit, not sure if I am understanding how variables are linked in R. Example below:

```
x1 <- ggplot() + geom_vline(xintercept = 10)
y1 <- x1

# x1 and y1 print plot with vline at 10

x1[["layers"]][[1]][["data"]][["xintercept"]] <- 20
y2 <- x1

 # x1 y2 and y1 print plot with vline at 20
# why is y1 being modified?
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732393/r-ggplot2-strange-behaviour-it-looks-its-passing-by-reference) answer your question? Essentially, it seems that `ggplot` objects are effectively reference types rather than value types.

Comment: @cazman Yes this explains the issue... I will attempt a few workarounds. Thanks for your input