# Ggplot uses reference of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, reference, aesthetics

If i pass a value to ggplot, it is stored as a reference so if it gets modified, the plot is changed as well. However, this only happens if it is given to the aes function, not the geom_hline in my example.

```
library(ggplot2)

# The line is at 10
value <- 10
pl <- ggplot() + geom_hline(yintercept=value)
value <- 0
pl

# The line is at 0
value <- 10
pl <- ggplot() + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=value))
value <- 0
pl
```

I believe this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732393/r-ggplot2-strange-behaviour-it-looks-its-passing-by-reference), but I don't understand what I can do to avoid this behaviour.
Can I force ggplot to make a copy of the data?

Regarding the use case, imagine I have a loop to plot many separate figures and `value` changes at each iteration of the loop.

```
plot_list <- NULL
for (value in 1:10) {
  # The title goes from 1 to 10 but all the lines are on 10.
  plot_list[[value]] <- ggplot() + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=value)) + labs(title=value)
}
plot_list
```

Comment: It’s a lazy evaluation problem. The plots are only created at the end of the loop, when `value` is `10`. The easiest solution is to switch the `fir` loop to `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your plot list is not really saving the object of the plot, but rather the code for the plot. I don't know exactly how to change that behavior, but your desired behavior is achieved quite easily with a map function.

First, make the plotting function, with value as input:

```
plotter <- function(value) {
  
  new_plot <- 
    ggplot() +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value))
  
  return(new_plot)
  
}
```

Map the function over your list of values, 1:10:

```
my_plots <- map(.x = 1:10, .f = plotter)
```

Now you can see that the ggplot objects in your saved list are updated appropriately:

```
my_plots[[1]]
my_plots[[5]]
```

I find map functions much more helpful and intuitive than looping in most cases, so I hope this helps!